# compare two images in PHP

Tags: php

I want to compare two images in PHP. If they are 95% or above similar then the result should be just displaying text Yes. If they are not similar the result should be No.
So

```
if ( ) 
{
echo "Yes";
}
else
{
echo "No";
}
```

Any way this is so far what I had found. http://pastebin.com/wgeu2DqE 
I would like to give you where I found it but you would have to register.

Now I have this function to load image

```
function LoadPNG($imgname)
{
    /* Attempt to open */
    $im = @imagecreatefrompng($imgname);

    /* See if it failed */
    if(!$im)
    {
        /* Create a blank image */
        $im  = imagecreatetruecolor(150, 30);
        $bgc = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
        $tc  = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

        imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 150, 30, $bgc);

        /* Output an error message */
        imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5, 'Error loading ' . $imgname, $tc);
    }

    return $im;
}
```

I've been trying on my notepad++ and phpdesigner to come up with something but I get errors. I am not a php developer so I am asking a help from you guys. I just need comparison between two images and Yes or No. So this is pretty easy. I saw this too but couldn't make sense out of it.

[Compare 2 images in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270929/compare-2-images-in-php)

Thanks.

Comment: I think an image recognition library would be your best bet.  Comparing images can be pretty complex, depending on how you define your comparison criteria.

Comment: "95% or above similar"? we need a solid definition for "similar"

Comment: You know, something like the guy in class wrote (pastebin link). If the difference is 0.95 or above they are the same. If not, they are not. If you have a better way tell me please. Explain about image recognition library?

Comment: difference of *what*? number of pixels which are *exactly* the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the compare in several ways, depending on what kind of compare you want and the use case. "Similar" is a very ambiguous term.

There are image comparing libraries, or you can use the ImageMagick functions. There is even a binding for [OpenCV](https://github.com/mgdm/OpenCV-for-PHP) to use with PHP.

Of course, the more complex the approach, the more flexible and better the results.

If you are comparing two images that ought to be equal and aren't (for example, say, two surveillance camera frames), you can use the DIY method given below.

If there are distortions in hue and luminosity (e.g. noise), then the DIY method will not work, but ImageMagick will give good results.

Finally if you're trying to map two views of the same object, e.g. from a camera that panned a foot to the left, or you are looking for an image "inside" another, etc., then OpenCV is the only viable alternative of the three.

A do-it-yourself approach, for **the simplest case**, could be to first check the aspect ratio of the two images, then reduce both to the same size (you can reduce them even further (say, scale 1:4) to filter out small differences and/or also reduce the work ahead).

At that point, you can compare the two images pixel by pixel using `getColorAt` (and also optionally convert to grayscale to ignore differences in hue). The distance between two pixels can also be calculated in several ways (e.g. with [CIE perceptual functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference)), or you can use the Euclidean distance - SQRT((r1-r2)**2 + (g1-g2)**2 + (b1-b2)**2).

Distance can range from 0 to W*H*255*SQRT(3); you can map linearly these values to the range 0-100%.

This can tell you easily the difference between an image, and the same image with some lines drawn on it. If you distort the image (e.g. with a "pinch" filter), or rotate it a little, the resulting image will appear 95%, even 99% identical, and yet this algorithm could well report a very low match (for photo quality pictures, with continuous tones, match will still be good. For cartoons, it will be very poor).

Comment: Now I see I should have mentioned the quality of the images I am working on. The thing is am not doing this for high tech stuff like camera frames. I am doing this because I need comparison between two simple png images on my computer. Other program languages failed me so PHP turned out to be the simplest solution for this.

I've seen something about imagemagic but wasn't able to make something out of it. Is there a simple code like what i have here that would work. http://pastebin.com/wrsFBG8u 
I managed to write this but I've got some errors and can't fix them . So what about this?

Comment: Your `imagehex()` function takes an array as argument, but you supply a GD object taken from `LoadPNG`. `imagehex()` then seems to behave as if it expected an image path, except that `type` is not available from `getImageSize()`. The code is enough to ask another question (a comment isn't enough for an answer), but I think you may not even need that. Feel free to contact me at (my userid) at (gmail), though. I am not clear at all about your second loop.

Comment: I found a solution that is good enough for me. I did a md5 check of two images and it worked. This will do enough for me. 

Thanks guys. And please can someone rate my posts so I can get points. That 15 points limit is preventing me from doing more work.

Comment: ...MD5? But that means you only need to know whether two images are identical bit by bit down to non-displayed metadata... it is quite different from what you were asking, IMO.

Comment: Yes, but this will do until I make "bullet proof" script. I am not working in HD pictures just simple .png files. MD5 works great on my comp and I will try make something out using hamming distance.