# How to compare 2 images in my FTP with PHP?

Tags: php, image, ftp

I have 2 images in my FTP : /var/www/image1.jpg and /home/image2.jpg

I need, in a PHP script, compare if these two images are the same or not like :

```
if(/var/www/image1.jpg == /home/image2.jpg){
    /blabla
}
```

I don't want tk know these differences, i just need to know if they are the same or not, do you have any ideas ?

Thanks !

Edit :

I use in PHP this for retrieve an image and upload on my FTP :

```
exec("wget -O ".$PATH."image.jpg --user=**** --password='****' http://URL");
```

I need to know if the old $PATH."image.jpg is exactlty the same as the new $PATH."image.jpg after my command exec().

If they are, i sleep() for many seconds...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare 2 images in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270929/compare-2-images-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate the hashes of the file and check whether they are equal and if so they might be the same.

```
if (sha1_file("path to to file 1") == sha1_file("path to t file 2")) 
    echo "Same";
```

Comment: Okay, and theses images are just a pixel difference, it's ok ? Considers that they are not the same ?

Comment: If these images are even one pixel different then this code will say they are different, but that's exactly what you asked in your question. If you want to find the difference, or know 'how' different they are in content, that is a totally different question with a much more complex answer...

Answer (score 2):

you can check from hash code of both file content (e.g. MD5, SHA1).

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to know if they're exact copies would be to read the files and create a hash from their content. Compare the hash's returned.