# Is it possible to compare images like two strings with levenshtein function?

Tags: php, c++, python, image, gd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compare 2 images in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270929/compare-2-images-in-php)

To compare two string for similarity I use levenshtein and similar_text function in php.

Is it possible to compare for similarity two images?

Why I need this?! I have two suppliers -> two sets of products. I need to have intersections between two sets. Sometimes products' names are different (0% similar) but actually they are the same.

So I guess, I can compare them by product photo.

Comment: "Sometimes products' names are different (0% similar) but actually they are the same." -- This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: This is harder to do than strings. How do you define a similar product photo? Keep in mind what a computer sees is not what a human sees.

Comment: @JoelCornett I think what he meant is two companies might call a product something different but they are the same product, so he wants to use images to compare them. For example, "LS YBD11" and "Louisville Slugger TPX Dynasty" are the same thing.

Comment: Yeah. Pitchinnate, you are right. I found some info about my question. TinEye.com is interesting app for searching similar images. Libpuzzle  - A library to find similar pictures. pHash - 
The open source perceptual hash library