# Getting Facebook profile picture as unique

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a method which takes a logged FB user to my app and takes its profile picture. Is there a way to identify a picture as unique?

I mean, if 2 persons upload same picture, same picture name, can both have the same picture id? is this picture unique? is there a way to get this picture as unique?

Comment: There is no such uniqueness. You would have to compare the actual image content to check whether two profile pictures are “identical”.

Comment: The main problem is that my original "myimage.jpg" it's renamed to "randomnameprofile1.jpg" and "anotherrandomnameprofile2.jpg" when uploading to Facebook profile. Don't know how to compare original and uploaded one

Comment: he did not mean to compare image names, he meant to compare the actual content of the image...

Comment: btw. why tag this with js sdk AND php sdk? there is not even any code from any sdk...

Comment: hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270929/compare-2-images-in-php

Comment: _"Don't know how to compare original and uploaded one"_ - _what for_ would you need to "compare" them? What you actually want to achieve here eventually, is still pretty unclear.